# How to hide windows console in c++ tcc

Tags: c++, windows, console, hide, tcc

How to hide console window,
Compiler is tiny C

```
//Tiny C -> http://download.savannah.gnu.org/releases/tinycc/
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    system("Taskkill /IM test.exe /F");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When operating system starts application, it lookups special description table in EXE file called [IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680339%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). This structure contains so called `Subsystem` field. When `Subsystem` is `IMAGE_SUBSYSTEM_WINDOWS_CUI` - OS attaches console window to this process. Otherwise, console window will not be added.

Compilers/linkers usually have parameters to set output application subsystem type, e.g. when you link your code using Microsoft Linker you can add `/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS` parameter and you will not see console window when starting your application.

The other way: compiler may automatically decide to set EXE subsystem to Console when seeing `main` function in your code, or set GUI subsystem when you have `WinMain` as entry point.

About TCC: I see `-Wl,-subsystem=gui` option in TCC documentation, but seems it is not worked. So try to send a bugreport or use more mature compiler/linker.